# The Four Horsemen Mod

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I started a new game and found all of them outside of Riverwood, I wasn't strong enough and ran away. Now that I am I can't find them can anyone help?

Comment: Also on ps4 forgot to add that tag

Comment: Keep adventuring: they're probably wandering around.

Answer (score -1):

I just had to delete then download again to solve issue.